# Explanations on the proof of lemma 2.5 of hungerford's Algebra?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Lemma 2.5.(v) $p^m\Bbb Z_{p^n}\cong \Bbb Z_{p^{n-m}}\ (m<n)$ where $p$ is prime.

And the proof goes $\ldots$

Note that $p^m\in \Bbb Z_{p^n}$ has order $p^{n-m}$. Therefore $p^m\Bbb Z_{p^n}=\langle p^m\rangle\cong \Bbb Z_{p^{n-m}}.\Box$

Could you please give me an elaboration?

Comment: What part of the proof do you not understand?

Comment: $\langle p^m\rangle\cong \Bbb Z_{p^{n-m}}$

Answer (score 2):

I will use $\mathbf{Z}/p^k$ to mean $\mathbf{Z}_{p^k}$

Well, $p^m \mathbf{Z}/p^n = \langle p^m \rangle$ is by definition.

Then let's consider $\langle p^m \rangle$ and $\mathbf{Z}/p^{n-m}$. The former is a cyclic group generated by $p^m$ which has order $p^{n-m}$. The latter is also a cyclic group of order $p^{n-m}$. By the uniqueness of cyclic groups, it is evident that they are isomorphic.

Comment: Do you mean order $p^{n-m}$?